# AngularJS provider upgrade for Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am working with AngularJS and now I want to move to angular4. I am reading that now I need to use class but not sure how.

First I want to convert this simple factory to class but I do not know where to start

```
angular.module('web-api-service', [])


.provider('webApi', [ function() {
    var nameUrlMap = {};

    var getUrl = function(name) {
        var ret = nameUrlMap[name];
        if (!ret) {
            throw new Error("Unable to find API URL for API " + name);
        }
        return marketServiceBase + ret;
    };

    this.registerApiUrl = function(name, url) {
        nameUrlMap[name] = url;
    };

    this.registerApiUrlCore = function(name, url) {
        nameUrlMap[name] = nameUrlMap[name] || url;
    };

    this.$get = function() {

        return {
            getUrl : getUrl
        };
    };
}]);
```

Can someone give me a hint how to start?

Comment: You are able to create `Service` in angular 4.

Comment: Are you building your angular 4 app form scratch or upgrading the existing angular 1 app to angular 4?

Comment: I want to build it from scratch and first job is to change this provider. But I Have no idea how to start. I know what service is.

Comment: The first thing to do is to read a book, or the documentation, about Angular. A decent book should, and the documentation does, cover services in depth.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly Angular is in `typescript` which has classes. Secondly there are only `services` left in angular no `factory`. Your code would go like a service as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }
   nameUrlMap = {};

    getUrl(name) {
        ret = this.nameUrlMap[name];
        if (!ret) {
            throw new Error("Unable to find API URL for API " + name);
        }
        return marketServiceBase + ret;
    };

    registerApiUrl(name, url) {
        this.nameUrlMap[name] = url;
    };

    registerApiUrlCore(name, url) {
        this.nameUrlMap[name] = this.nameUrlMap[name] || url;
    };

}
```

Add comments for futher help.

Comment: this is complete you are looking for. Not just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is the most commonly used language for angular 4, so I'll show you the example in typescript.

You need to start with creating a class of the name you want. I have commented in the code below. You can have a read. For details go to [angular](http://angular.io).

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder} from "@angular/forms";

@Injectable() // => annotation to tell angular that this class is going to be used as a service which can/will be
// injected to others
export default class WebApi { // => export the class

    nameUrlMap = {}; // => declare class variable. These are public you can declare them as private. if they are
    // public they can be accessed from other classes using the injected object.
    private marketServiceBase: string;

    constructor(private xyz: FormBuilder) {
        // you inject your dependencies here. Dependencies can be other, I
        // have injected FormBuilder for reference
        // services/constants etc
    }
    
    //a public function accessible outside this class with the injected object. This is like returning from the
    // service in angular 1
    getUrl(name) {
        let ret = this.nameUrlMap[name];
        if (!ret) {
            throw new Error("Unable to find API URL for API " + name);
        }
        return this.marketServiceBase + ret;
    };
    // private function not accessible outside this class 
    private registerApiUrl(name, url) {
        this.nameUrlMap[name] = url;
    };

    private registerApiUrlCore(name, url) {
        this.nameUrlMap[name] = this.nameUrlMap[name] || url;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you too to use the angular [CLI](https://cli.angular.io/).

And to complete this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) provided by the angular team.

So you can create a new service with a simple instruction: ng new service services/myService, and it will include the new service in your project, ready to be used

---

With angular 4, you'll need to get started in **TypeScript**, thats why Angular 1.x is called Angular**JS**,(JavaScript).

*I am reading that now I need to use class but not sure how.* -> In TypeScript, all directives and components are classes with decorators.

Is not that easy to migrate an angularjs app to angular2-4-5, so you should start learning it from the beggining

Answer (score 1):

Create a class say `WebApi` whose constructor accepts a parameter of `url`.

```
@Injectable
export class WebApi {
    constructor(url: string) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    // the other relevant code of your provider goes here.
}
```

In your `app.module` file, you would need to add this as a provider using `useFactory`.

```
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: WebApi, useFactory: () => new WebApi(API_URL) }
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need create typescript file in app folder like this
[image]

for example i create a file name gen-function.module.ts and then add your own class. here is my example

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class GenFunctionProvider{
    getLink(msg : any)
    {

      return 'your URl';
    }
}
```

Dont forget to add your provider on your app.module.ts like this

```
import { GenFunctionProvider } from'./gen-function.module';
```

and add in @ngModule like this

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ....
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      entryComponents: [....],
      providers: [GenFunctionProvider],
      bootstrap: [....]
    })
```